# Wordpress: generate webpages from database entries

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is a shot in the dark, but I don't know how to effectively voice my issue in a Google search.

I have a Wordpress site (mostly coded in PHP) and a MySQL database.

In the database I have a table called `housing` with the fields `id`, `title` and `description` to name a few.

I want to generate a page for each element in the `housing` table from the same template that showcases the data in that table row, and with a URL like `mysite.com/housing/{housing_id}/`

I would also like these pages to be deleted if the corresponding database entry is deleted.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for dynamic URLs in PHP will put you in the right direction.
The rest depends on how well you know PHP :)

Comment: I'm comfortable with PHP, I haven't used it on this scale in a long time so I'm a bit rusty, I'm also very ready to learn (if you have any tutorials etc I am interested!)

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to post links. A great tutorial on first page of Google results. Have a go and post up anything you need explaining

Comment: Thanks! I shall do :)